# How can I send a bundle array to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have an array of `Bundle` and I'm going to send it to another activity

**Transmitter:**

```
List<Bundle> items = new ArrayList<>();
// add items

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dialog.class);
intent.putExtra("items", items.toArray());
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiver:**

```
Bundle[] items = (Bundle[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("items");
```

**But its return error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.items.ReceverActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.os.Bundle[]
```

Comment: `Bundle Array` what's this?

Comment: Bundle[] or bundle.toArray()

Comment: Isnt it enough to but items in ONE bundle do you need to have an array of bundles?

Comment: no items is NOT one bundle it is a list that will be converted to an array

Comment: getExtras only returns one Bundle either so sth is fail in your code

Comment: Yeah I get it that it is not ONE Bundle!!!Thats what I asked: Are you sure you need multiple Bundles?

Comment: @IljaKO yes i am sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundle does not `Serializable`, but it does implement `Parcelable`. You can use [putParcelableArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) to pass your `ArrayList<Bundle>`, and [getParcelableArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)) to retrieve it. There is also a pair to pass and retrieve an array, you have to use array